# Change key of entries in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm currently trying to build a complex function to re-order the positions of some sections (div's) which are defined in a PHP array.

So for example I've this array here:

```
$sections = array(
    0 => 'section_one',
    1 => 'section_two',
    2 => 'section_three',
    3 => 'section_four',
    4 => 'section_five',
    5 => 'section_six',
    6 => 'section_seven'
);
```

Which turns out like this:

```
array(7) { [0]=> string(11) "section_one" [1]=> string(11) "section_two" [2]=> string(13) "section_three" [3]=> string(12) "section_four" [4]=> string(12) "section_five" [5]=> string(11) "section_six" [6]=> string(13) "section_seven" }
```

When the user moves now the section six before section two on my website, I need to change the key of section six to 1 and move every key one number up after the moved section. So `section_two` becomes the key `2` and so on...

Any idea how I can do this? I know that I can replace keys this way:

```
$arr[ $newkey ] = $arr[ $oldkey ];
unset( $arr[ $oldkey ] );
```

When the user finished a move of an element, I know the name like section_six and the new position of the element.

After re-ordering / re-placing the keys, the array must look like this:

```
$sections_a = array(
    0 => 'section_one',
    1 => 'section_six',
    2 => 'section_two',
    3 => 'section_three',
    4 => 'section_four',
    5 => 'section_five',
    6 => 'section_seven'
);
```

Comment: Can you please provide the sample output?

Comment: Of the array or the sections on the website?

Comment: The array......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to copy the array and use [`array_splice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)

```
$sections = array(
    0 => 'section_one',
    1 => 'section_two',
    2 => 'section_three',
    3 => 'section_four',
    4 => 'section_five',
    5 => 'section_six',
    6 => 'section_seven'
);

$oldkey = 5;
$newkey = 1;

$sections_a = $sections;
array_splice( $sections_a, $newkey, 0, array_splice( $sections_a, $oldkey, 1) );
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => section_one
    [1] => section_six
    [2] => section_two
    [3] => section_three
    [4] => section_four
    [5] => section_five
    [6] => section_seven
)
```

Comment: I've did something wrong with the result array. Please see. I've forgot to remove section_six from the old position.

Comment: Updated answer @Mr.Jo

Comment: Do I need to copy it? Or can I use $sections instead?

Comment: You can use `$sections` :)

Answer (score 1):

I see @Eddie has given a better solution than mine thanks Eddie,
but here is the custom function I made for this if it helps anyone.

```
// This function returns the new array
function reindexArray($array,       // Array
                      $index,       // Index of the value that you to change the index of
                      $indexToMove) // Index that you want to move that value
{
    // Store the value to be reindex in a variable
    $reIndexedValue = $array[$index];
    // Remove that value from the array
    unset($array[$index]);
    // Reorder the original array
    $oldArrayInOrder = array_values($array);
    // Create a new array
    $newArray = array();
    // Now reindex all the value into the new array in the proper order
    for ($j=0, $i=0; $i < count($oldArrayInOrder)+1; $i++) { 
        if($i == $indexToMove)
        {
            $newArray[$i]=$reIndexedValue; 
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            $newArray[$i] = $oldArrayInOrder[$j];
            $j++;
        }
    }
    return($newArray);
}
```